# Дублирование записей в бд

Tags: mysql

Задача следующая.Есть страничка,котору надо продублировать несколько раз,и все записи из таблиц которые ей соответствуют,ну естественно ID у всех потом поменять на нужный.Какой вариант самый быстрый и удобный? Пока что лишь в голову пришло в каждом таблице делать вставку на основе запроса,и потом меня айди,но так до утра буду точно возиться,таблиц около 10 и в каждой так играться займет много времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO articles (text,author, ... ) SELECT (text, author, ... ) FROM articles WHERE id (1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

Что-то в таком духе, короче, используй INSERT ... SELECT

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: INSERT INTO products(lp_id,title_ro,title_ru,title_en,pieces_in_pack,pieces_box,gros,lat,cant)
SELECT lp_id,title_ro,title_ru,title_en,pieces_in_pack,pieces_box,gros,lat,cant
FROM products
WHERE lp_id = 4

Comment: То есть с каждой таблицей так играться и руками потом айди менять?

Comment: WHERE id **IN** (1,2,3,4,5,6,7);

Comment: id сами проставятся автоматом, если у поля id есть флаг AUTO_INCREMET. И скорее всего он есть.

Comment: Автоинкремент это понятно,есть еще и lp_id это как я понял уже руками придется апдейтить

Comment: Можно вот так попробовать:
INSERT INTO articles (text,author, ip_id) SELECT (text, author, ip_id + 3 ) ...

Ну т.е. к выбираемому столбцу применить какуб-нибудь арифметическу3ю операцию, например.

Comment: Спасибо попробую